# Onclick change div style + onclick outside div remove style change

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I would like to change the style on a div with an onclick... and remove the style when clicking somewhere outside of the div.

I have the following code setup... can someone help me to remove the style on the divs if you click anywhere else on the page?

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
     .account{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
     }
    .selected{
     border: 2px solid #F00;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".account").click(function(){
   $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
   $(this).addClass("selected");
  });   
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>the test</h1>
 <div class="account">test 1</div>
 <div class="account">test 2</div>
</body>
```

Thank you very much for any help you can give me!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".account").click(function(e){
       $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
       $(this).addClass("selected");
       e.stopPropagation();//This will stop the event bubbling 
   });   

   //This event handler will take care of removing the class if you click anywhere else
   $(document).click(function(){ 
       $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
   });
});
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/yLhsC/

Note that you can use `on` or `delegate` to handle click event on `account` elements if there are many on the page.

Something like this.

Using `on` if using jQuery 1.7+

```
$('parentElementContainingAllAccounts').on('click', '.account', function(e){
     $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
     $(this).addClass("selected");
     e.stopPropagation();//This will stop the event bubbling 
});
```

Using `delegate`

```
$('parentElementContainingAllAccounts').delegate('.account', 'click', function(e){
     $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
     $(this).addClass("selected");
     e.stopPropagation();//This will stop the event bubbling 
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The following should do it:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if($(e.target).hasClass('account')) {
        // do style change
    }
    else {
        // undo style change  
    }
});
```

It binds the event handler to the entire document, so you'd have problems with any event handlers on more specific elements that call `e.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior with attaching click listener on body element e.g.:

```
$("body").click(function(){

});
```

Comment: this handler will still fire when you click on the actual target.

Comment: yes, that's true... sorry, forgot to mention that you will have to add  in div click handler return false;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.account').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});


$(document).click(function(){  
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
});
});
```